# one query to add a field for duplicate values in a column (oracle)

Tags: sql, oracle

Assume a table:

```
--------------------------------
Col A | Col B | Col C | Col D
--------------------------------
  xx     xxx    xxxx     2000
  xx     xxx    xxxx     3000
  xx     xxx    xxxx     2000
  xx     xxx    xxxx     1450
  xx     xxx    xxxx     1000
  xx     xxx    xxxx     2000
  xx     xxx    xxxx     1000
```

I want to have a query to have a column of value that presents whether if there a value in col D has the same value in the column, so that

```
-------------------------------------
Col A | Col B | Col C | Col D | Col E
-------------------------------------
  xx     xxx    xxxx     2000    Y
  xx     xxx    xxxx     3000    N
  xx     xxx    xxxx     2000    Y
  xx     xxx    xxxx     1450    N
  xx     xxx    xxxx     1000    Y
  xx     xxx    xxxx     2000    Y
  xx     xxx    xxxx     1000    Y
```

It will be even better to have the column shows how many duplicates

```
-------------------------------------
Col A | Col B | Col C | Col D | Col E
-------------------------------------
  xx     xxx    xxxx     2000    3
  xx     xxx    xxxx     3000    1
  xx     xxx    xxxx     2000    3
  xx     xxx    xxxx     1450    1
  xx     xxx    xxxx     1000    2
  xx     xxx    xxxx     2000    3
  xx     xxx    xxxx     1000    2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just want `count(*)` as a window function:

```
select t.*,
       count(*) over (partition by d) as e
from t;
```

Comment: thanks, what about it has to partition on 2 columns, like composite key, is that ok to

Comment: @Dreamer . . . You can partition by multiple columns, even expressions.